# No idea how to get rid of fatal error after closing turtle based program

Tags: windows, python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller, turtle-graphics

So,i know why the error happens,i packed the python script into an exe with pyinstaller and i disabled the console therefore the fatal error which says `"failed to execute the script "name""` pops up and i know that it happens because of breaking turtle with `turtle.bye()` ,even as that,i've tried stopping turtle with `turtle.onclick()` and same thing happened.How do i get rid of that error? :( Thanks for the help,it's really bugging me out because other than that,the program works as intended.

Comment: Have you tried `turtle.done()` in replacement of `.bye` ?

Comment: Hey ^^ replacing it with that makes it so that the program doesn't exit anymore when i press the button that i've bound the quit function to.